# Find Bezier control points P1 and P2 given P0, P3 and B(t) as knowns

Tags: cubic-bezier

I'll be doing this in LUA. 2D cubic bezier curve.

I know the start and end points of the curve and I have an arbitrary point with x,y,t all known.

I have tried to apply de Casteljau to this so:

- I know that I want to find P[1][0] and P[2][0] given that I know P[0][0] and P[3][0] and P[0][3].
- I understand that P[i][j] = (1-t)P[i][j-1] + (t)P[i+1][j-1]

But I cannot find a way to complete the solution chain with the givens that I have.

I have searched this and other forums for info on this but none I found gives a concrete approach to coding the solution.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's "it can't be done without making assumptions about ..."

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate for the math stack exchange?

Comment: @Rob I looked at the Math Stack Exchange - it didn't help with anything that looked close to being a practical coding solution (even pseudocode) which is what I was hoping to find... but if the sentiment here is "not something we can help with" then I'll just say thanks for listening and I'll head off elsewhere ....